# presenting numeric value in radgrid inform of a predefined words

Tags: c#

i have a radgrid whose datasource is from a web service and i need  a certain column named "StatusId" to show either "ACTIVE " or "INACTIVE".This is whereby if the status Is 1,then instead of showing "1"it should show "Active" else "inactive"

Your ideas welcomed.

Comment: Use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick web search [reveals](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/convert-grid-column-value-from-boolean-to-customized-string-and-applying-filter-on-column.aspx) you can change text in the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    var gridDataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    if (gridDataItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (gridDataItem["YourColumn"].Text == "Original")
    {
        gridDataItem["YourColumn"].Text = "Replaced";
    }
}
```